# What Crash Conditions Result in a Crash Dump?

Tags: c++, crash-dumps

I have [enabled crash dump collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps) on my Windows 10 laptop, but I have been surprised at how Windows becomes fickle about when to collect a crash dump.  I made a C++ console application, as a release build, and tried purposely crashing the app a couple different ways:

- `throw 15;`
- `throw std::invalid_argument("Oops!");`
- `float foo = 1.0 / 0.0;`

The first two attempts do indeed result in a crash dump file being generated.  However, simply dividing by zero causes the application to exit silently...no crash dump.

I also found that if I make a debug build of the same application, I still get no dump for divide by zero, but the first two exceptions cause a CRT dialogue to pop-up with "abort, retry or ignore".  In this case it will create a crash dump only if I select "retry."  I wish there was an explanation about that.

But my real question is trying to understand why I can't get a crash dump from a divide by zero.  Is there any configuration change I could make to fix that?  For example, I have access to the tool BugTrap.  Perhaps instead of configuring WER I should configure BugTrap...and maybe it can capture a crash dump in a divide by zero event?

### Update

PEBKAC.  My divide by zero of floating point numbers was not resulting in any error at all.  If I want to get a crash from a divide by zero, I need to (1) turn these into integers and (2) try to print out the result.  That latter "part 2" I suspect is a consequence of code optimization...if the result of my division operation was unused, then it didn't get executed.  I don't have another explanation.

Comment: From the link in your question - “ Applications that do their own custom crash reporting, **including .NET applications**, are not supported by this feature.”

Comment: Dividing by zero is undefined behavior.  For Windows, I think if you fiddle with the CPU flags, you can force it to crash on a divide by 0 (but it's been a long time since I've done this).

Comment: I'm surprised that floating point division by zero ends your program. Normally it would just assign infinity to your `foo` variable.

Comment: [This may help](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_handle.html).  I remember a long time ago I had to debug a program that crashed on divide by 0, all caused by a printer driver setting the floating point flags on the CPU (I won't mention the printer company).

Comment: [Try calling _controlfp on program startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/control87-controlfp-control87-2?view=vs-2019).  If you want to make sure your program crashes on divide by 0, see if setting the requisite flags works.

Comment: I met the enemy, it is me.  See my posted update.

Comment: Why would you want a crash on divide by zero?   Wouldn't it be better to prevent such operations in the first place (e.g. check the operands before dividing, and do something else if the denominator is zero - or, better yet, design the code that sets up inputs to ensure the denominator is never zero).   As a general rule, trapping an error condition and then dealing with the consequences (e.g. working out what other errors occur because of the first error) is much more demanding than preventing the error in the first place.